# how can I launch an x window inside a vim window

Tags: command-line, xorg, vim, tty

I have stopped using my desktop manager in favor of consoles.

I can "startx myProgram" to launch a dedicated window; however I would like to use a window in Vim instead of the entire console.

When attempting this in Vim the entire screen is taken over.